# Reading a set of letters using scanf statement in c

Tags: c

I am trying to take input using scanf with the condition that

1. first letter should start with c,d,e
2. there should be no vowels in the scanned text which satisfied condition (1)
   Else
   neglect the input
   And my goal here is to perform this only through scanf function and in one line.

I have tried this

```
scanf("%[c]%[^[aeiou\n]]",a);
```

But when I am trying to print (a) it's just printing 'c' .
Please help me where I am doing mistake.
I am opened to new ideas.

This is what I am getting for the following input
Input :

```
cdfgt
```

Output:

```
c
```

The required output should be
Output:

```
cdfgt
```

Comment: For complex input formats, `scanf` and family is simply not good enough. Read a line in full, and try to verify that it matches your required format (possibly through the use of regular expressions).

Comment: What is `a` defined as?

Comment: it is just declared

Comment: Please include that declaration as well.

Comment: There are two conversion specifiers, so you need two variables to store the results in.

Comment: It is declared as ( char a[20]; )

Comment: @sahithkumar use `fgets` and parse the string yourself as suggested by the 1st comment. `scanf` is just not made for user input. That's roughly 3-4 lines of simple code to write.

Comment: Your `scanf` is looking for 2 strings and you're only providing `a` to store them in - better to do what the others have suggested and not use `scanf` though